# data_mapper: Can't save Time object

Tags: ruby, sqlite, datamapper, sqlite3-ruby, ruby-2.1

I am attempting to persist an object that has a Time-type field. On create, I attempt to set the `sleep_value` to a valid Time object but the save seems to fail silently (even though `raise_on_save_failure` is set to true).

If I try to search for the object via `Sleep.all` or `Sleep.get(1)`, i am getting an error `argument out of range`.

The only value I can pass it to make it persist is `Time.now()`. If I do a `Sleep.all`, that object with `sleep_time => Time.now` is returned.

```
gems:    
data_mapper (1.2.0)   
sqlite3 (1.3.10)


require 'sqlite3'
require 'data_mapper'

DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/test.db")

DataMapper::Model.raise_on_save_failure = true

class Sleep

    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id,           Serial
    property :sleep_time,   Time

end

DataMapper.finalize.auto_migrate!

Sleep.create(:sleep_time => Time.new(2015, 10, 1))

Sleep.all
```

UPDATE: I have done a bit more trial and error and have found the following values are compatible with the time field (changed the name from sleep_time to st)

```
Sleep.create(:st => (Time.now - 1))
Sleep.create(:st => Time.at((Time.now - Time.at(1000))))
```

And the following values do not save (no error is thrown but records are nt persisted)

```
Sleep.create(:st => Time.new(2015, 10, 1, 2, 2, 2, "+02:00"))
Sleep.create(:st => Time.new(2002))
Sleep.create(:st => Time.new((Time.now - Time.new(2002)))) #out of range
Sleep.create(:st => Time.at(2)) #out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the fact that I could use with Time.now() and made this helper method. I call it to save my Time properties.

def self.convert_to_dm_friendly_time(target_time)

```
today = Time.now
return today + target_time.to_i - today.to_i #basically starting the object from today and then taking today out.

end
```

Damn, this was an ugly solution. Surely there is an easier way?